# My Solution to the Largest Palindrome of the product of two 3 digit numbers needs work

Tags: javascript, palindrome

The answer I'm getting is not the correct one (correct answer is 906609). Please help me understand where I am going wrong. I want the while loop to go from 100 to 999 while multiplying itself against the current `i` value before the loop increments it.

```js
// A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.

// Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

var pali = [];

function palindrome() {
for (var i = 100; i <= 999; i++) {
    var counter = 100;
    
    while (counter <= 999) {
      var result = counter * i;
      if (result.toString() === result.toString().split("").reverse().join("")) {
        pali.push(result);
      }   
      counter++;
    }
}
  return pali[pali.length - 1];
}

console.log(palindrome());
```

Comment: *"The answer I'm getting is not the correct one."* What is the answer you are getting and what do you expect instead? Please read [ask].

Comment: Exhibit A to my PS rant. See below for an example of a decent programmer  / person Felix Kling

Comment: I'm sorry if you feel that way. If you say "it isn't correct", information about what the incorrect result and correct results are makes it easier for others to help you. You can't be angry about the fact that others try to improve your question to get better/faster help, can you? :) Don't take it personal. The main goal is to solve a problem. The more information is available (problem description) and the easier it is to consume the information (question formatting), the easier it is for others to help you.

Comment: @DevoidDesign When you post a question on SO, It is similar to writing code, in the sense that it is written once, but read a lot of time. So it is always  a good thing to add as much clarity as Felix points out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to sort the array in ascending order if you want the last one to be the highest:

```
pali.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
```

Using that, I get 906609.

Comment: No problem. Honestly, you may want to change your algorithm so that you're keeping track of the highest one as you iterate over the possibilities instead of just pushing it into an array that needs to be sorted to find the highest one. That way in the end you just return the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Lengthier, but faster. Starting at the max values and working down, short circuiting when we won't find higher values:

```js
function largestPalindromeProduct(lower, upper) {
  var palindrome = 0;
  var outerLow = lower;
  var outer = upper;
  while (outer > outerLow) {
    var inner = upper;
    var innerLow = lower;
    while (inner > innerLow) {
      var result = inner * outer;
      if (result + "" === (result + "").split("").reverse().join("")) {
        if (result > palindrome) {
          palindrome = result;
          outerLow = inner; // Don't go lower than this value in the outer, no need!
        }
        inner = innerLow; // short-circuit this loop
      }
      inner--;
    }
    outer--;
  }
  return palindrome;
}

console.log(largestPalindromeProduct(100, 999))
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way will be to add a If statement.

```
function palindrome() 
    {
        var max = 0;
        for (var i = 999; i >= 100; i--) 
        {
            var counter = 999;
            while (counter >= 100) 
            {
                var result = counter * i;
                if (result.toString() === result.toString().split("").reverse().join("")) 
                {
                    if(result>max)
                    {
                         max = result;
                    }
                }   
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return max;
     }
```